# Vi Editior Navigator Not Working Properly in Solaris 10

Tags: linux, solaris, vi, solaris-10

I am using ViEditor :
This is my code of line :

```
sh /u02/oraprod/prod/db/tech_st/11.1.0/appsutil/scripts/PROD_hooradb2/adautocfg.sh appspass=apps > $HOME/LOG/autocfg.log
perl /u02/oraprod/prod/db/tech_st/11.1.0/appsutil/scripts/PROD_hooradb2/myadpreclone.pl dbTier > $HOME/LOG/prcln.log
cd /u02/oraprod/prod/db/tech_st/11.1.0/admin/PROD_hooradb2/diag/rdbms/prod/PROD/cdump/core_26676
cat core >> coredump
```

When I am moving cursor line "`/u02/oraprod/prod/db/tech_st/11.1.0/admin/PROD_hooradb2/diag/rdbms/prod/PROD/cdump/core_26676` "

it is copying the above line word by word on the movement of cursor 
"`perl /u02/oraprod/prod/db/tech_st/11.1.0/appsutil/scripts/PROD_hooradb2/myadpreclone.pl dbTier > $HOME/LOG/prcln.log`"

Why is this happening ??

I am using this :

```
bash-3.00$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue Connect via ftp or ftps !!

Comment: This answer makes no sense - you can't run vi over ftp.

Comment: @alanc..

Yes I cant run it over ftp. But I can make changes on the file through ftp by downloading it..
As it was a script that ran on a scheduled timing.So, it sort of did the job for me.